# Vectorised code for selecting elements of a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Well the following code obviously returns the element in position `ind` in matrix:

```
def select_coord(a,ind):
    return a[ind]
```

However I don't know how to vectorise this. In other words:

```
b=np.asarray([[2,3,4,5],[7,6,8,10]])
indices=np.asarray([2,3])
select_coord(b,indices)
```

Should return `[4,10]`.

Which can be written with a for loop:

```
def new_select_record(a,indices):
    ret=[]
    for i in range a.shape[0]:
        ret.append(a[indices[i]])
    return np.asarray(ret)
```

Is there a way to write this in a vectorised manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `b[0, 2]`, `b[1, 3]`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> b = np.array([[2,3,4,5], [7,6,8,10]])
>>> indices = np.array([2, 3])
>>> b[np.arange(len(indices)), indices]
array([ 4, 10])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what is the difference between ':' and `arange`?  is this the thing that makes the miracle?

Comment: @Naji, `numpy.arange(3)` gives you `array([0, 1, 2])`. I don't know point of asking about `:`..

Comment: Well I imagined there is no difference between np.arange(2) and passing ':' for the first dimension, but mine returns a (2,2) shaped array and yours returns a (1,2) which is the desired one.(I mean replace in your code the 4th line with b[:, indices].

Comment: @Naji, `b[:, [2,3]]` gives you `[b[0,2], b[0,3]], [b[1,2], b[1,3]]], ...`.

Comment: oops! my mistake+apologies.

Answer (score 1):

how about: `np.diag(b[:,[2,3]])`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. And how can I change them in place?